# Show all x-axis values on plot - Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am attempting to show all x-axis values when I plot a line-graph in Bokeh.

Currently, the output is as follows;

[image]

The x-axis range is from 0-10, and I would like all to be displayed.

I have seen in a previous solution that `p.yaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"` worked for the y-axis. However this was unsuccessful for the x-axis.

Any assistance that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `major_label_orientation` only controls what direction the text is rendered in, it has not nothing to do with what ticks are chosen to be displayed. But you need to be specific about what you mean. There are infinite number of values between 0 and 10 so what does "would like all to be displayed" actually mean?

Comment: The there are 11 groups which, all of which occur consecutively, which need to be plotted to the x axis. These groups are represented as integers (1 to 11) in a Pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
p.xaxis.ticker = list(range(1, 12))
```

or the more explicit:

```
p.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=list(range(1, 12))
```